# Origin of singular moduli

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms

Books on modular forms don't usually attribute the main results to anyone. For instance, who first obtained that values of the $j$ invariant at quadratic imaginary points (singular moduli) are algebraic integers?

More generally, is there a good source for historical accounts on the arithmetic theory of modular forms?

Comment: Your title and question body seem unrelated. The theory of modular forms has its roots in the classical theory of elliptic integrals, elliptic functions and theta functions. Without this background the theory of modular forms appears quite unmotivated.

Comment: Singular moduli is the usual name people give to values of the j invariant at quadratic imaginary points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This goes back to Kronecker. See "Kronecker's Jugendtraum and Modular Functions" by Vladut.

Also see the first two sections [here](https://ctnt-summer.math.uconn.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/1632/2016/02/CTNTmodularforms.pdf), the second section [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/cfthistory.pdf), and Sections 1, 3, and 4 [here](https://www.emis.de/journals/SC/1998/3/pdf/smf_sem-cong_3_243-273.pdf).